# Logging with akka. app design

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka

Suppose I have scala app that is based on `Futures`, on `scala.concurrent` to handle the asyn / concurency (no actors were used so far).

In many places I use log4j for loggining stuff into log file. 
Since it is I/O I suppose I may improve performance by sending the log message to LoggingActor

something like this:

```
def stuffTodo(arg:String)(implicit ex:ExecutionContext) : Future[Result] = {

 // important performant work
 // .. 
 logAcrot ! LogMessage("message-1")
 // ...
}
```

where msg: `case class LogMessage(msg:String, implicit ex:ExecutionContext)`

then in `ActorLog`

```
def receive = {
    case LogMessage(msg:String, ex:ExecutionContext) ⇒ {log.info(msg + ex)}
}
```

I've seen other approaches that basically **wrap** `scala.concurent.ExecutionContext` (with current thread) and use [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)-magic (log4j) and do logging by attaching the thread-id to the log-message. But ultimately it blocks/slows down the thread/execution (as far as I understand) and makes the app slower.

In this case with this Actor, the logging stays independent / async and sequential at the same time.

Is it a good idea to go this way? Sharing experience story? pros/cons/concerns? Asking before trying on heavy load..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka already had good support for logging, which is documentated on the page [Logging - Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html).  I don't think it's necessary or desirable to create a logger actor in your system particularly when this mechanism already exists.

You may already use the `LoggingAdaptor` class that performs logging asynchronously, it does this by posting it onto an event-bus.  You should be able to use this same mechanism in an actor or outside.

Take a look at [Logging.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/Logging.scala)

***Logging Mixin***

Scala has a mixin for actors, that creates the logger for the actor and allows the MDC to be set. From documentation:

```
import Logging.MDC

final case class Req(work: String, visitorId: Int)

    class MdcActorMixin extends Actor with akka.actor.DiagnosticActorLogging {
        var reqId = 0

        override def mdc(currentMessage: Any): MDC = {
           reqId += 1
           val always = Map("requestId" -> reqId)
           val perMessage = currentMessage match {
              case r: Req => Map("visitorId" -> r.visitorId)
              case _      => Map()
           }
           always ++ perMessage
        }

       def receive: Receive = {
           case r: Req => {
              log.info(s"Starting new request: ${r.work}")
           }
       }
}
```

**Logging outside an actor**

There are two examples in the `Logging.scala` file of createing a LoggingSource outside of an actor:

```
trait MyType { // as an example
  def name: String
}

implicit val myLogSourceType: LogSource[MyType] = new LogSource[MyType] {
  def genString(a: MyType) = a.name
}

class MyClass extends MyType {
  val log = Logging(eventStream, this) // will use "hallo" as logSource
  def name = "hallo"
}
```

> The second variant is used for including the actor system’s address:

```
 trait MyType { // as an example
   def name: String
 }

 implicit val myLogSourceType: LogSource[MyType] = new LogSource[MyType] {
   def genString(a: MyType) = a.name
   def genString(a: MyType, s: ActorSystem) = a.name + "," + s
 }

 class MyClass extends MyType {
   val sys = ActorSystem("sys")
   val log = Logging(sys, this) // will use "hallo,akka://sys" as logSource
   def name = "hallo"
  }
```

The MDC can be set on the logging adaptor if you need it.

***Logging Thread and MDC***

The documentation also covers your point on the logging thread, when the logging is asynchronously performed by another thread.

> Since the logging is done asynchronously the thread in which the
>   logging was performed is captured in Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)
>   with attribute name sourceThread. With Logback the thread name is
>   available with %X{sourceThread} specifier within the pattern layout
>   configuration.

Comment: following your link: I did just this: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/logging/LogSample.scala

seems works. but still should figure out how to make layout work/applied: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/logback.xml

Comment: Nice.  I've updated the answer a bit for others using some of the examples from the Logging file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like over engineering.

I would go with **logback**, and implement custom asynchonous **Appender**, if I would do something like this, so I would not have to change my code, if I decide not to discontinue.

Otherwise logging libraries are pretty good bet, I would try maybe tuning it to get better performance, and rely on others experience in implementing this feature.